# How do I write this postgres query for a has-many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a classroom table. And each classroom has many classroom users.

A classroom_user has a `kind` attribute, which is either `teacher` or `student`.  Each `classroom_user` is associated with a user_id from the Users table.

What I'm looking for: I want to find all of the classrooms for a given teacher and student.

Comment: Can you post sample  structure as formatted text?

Comment: Look up JOIN in the text book you use in your sql class.